# Historical stats on capacity shortages in the EC2 spot instance market

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Recently I'm getting lots of spot instances terminated with the following message:

> instance-terminated-no-capacity: Your Spot instance was terminated because there is no Spot capacity available that matches your request

When deciding whether to use spot instances and which instance type to use, I'd like to know how often a instance class/type/region combination runs into capacity shortages.  Is there any way of getting timeseries stats on this, through an API or web console?

Answer (score 5):

Trying to explain the (spot) instance market is like trying to explain oil and petrol products in a commodities market. Analysts think they have some explanation for price volatility but no one really has a complete picture of buyer behavior.

There is no avoiding spot terminations, they the leftovers that were available at the time. To keep up capacity, use [spot fleets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html) of type maintain based on instances you like in the [spot instance advisor](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/).

Comment: I agree that we're missing some key pieces of information, such as the demand for on-demand/reserved instances and entire supply size.  However, it seems like the idea is that as supply shrinks, the market's spot price should go up.  That won't be true if all spot supply disappears in one fell swoop, but shouldn't the prices rise otherwise?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Most people are using spot instances for cheap, non-critical instances, so their bids are likely to all be low. There'll be capacity until there pretty much suddenly isn't.

Comment: @conradlee the problem with that assumption is that in late 2017 AWS changed the spot pricing algorithm to substantially reduce volatility.  Spot prices do signal demand but the demand signals have been dampened to the point that they no longer clearly signal capacity.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks! I thought some kind of change like this took place behind the scenes.  I'm very curious to learn more here.  I'll create a separate question for that.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot here's the new question: https://serverfault.com/questions/937354/at-a-high-level-how-are-ec2-spot-prices-and-availability-determined-after-the-u  If you know any more details I'd love to hear therem there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can get the **pricing history** and create some *charts* or maybe *machine learning* analysis.

You can use **AWS CLI** and its **aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history** command. It accepts a lot of parameters to narrow down the price history you want to a specific region, availability zone, instance type, etc:

```
~ $ aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history
      [--filters <value>]
      [--instance-types <value>]
      [--availability-zone <value>]
      [--start-time <value>]
      [--end-time <value>]
      [--product-descriptions <value>]
      ...
```

Be aware that by default it returns *a lot of data* - it may look like it stalls so give it some time or narrow down the scope with parameters.

Also depending on your *aws-cli* configuration it may return JSON by default. If you prefer *tab separated values* use `aws --output=text ...`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks @Mlu.  I know the historical data for the price is available, both in the web console and in the API.  The thing that's not there though is any data on 'Spot capacity'.  I want to prevent my machines from being terminated for any spot cause--both being outbid and due to spot capacity shortages--my question is about getting data on the latter.

Comment: I’m afraid they are related - the message says “there is not enough spot capacity *that matches your request*”, i.e. capacity *at the price you bid*. I’m pretty sure that if you bid at $100/hr for a t2.small it would never get terminated. Hence you need to analyse the past prices to figure out a bid price at which your instance will unlikely be terminated.